# SIGSEGV libdvm.so woes

Tags: android

Have been spending more time than I care on this problem and looking for ideas of where/how to proceed.

First, my dev console reported that one of my users crashed which I am assuming at launch since crashlytics never reported the incident to me.

- Droid Ultra w/KitKat

I am participating in Google's Pre-Launch Report and consistently there are 5 devices that fail with similar SIGSEGV.

- HTC One (M8) w/KitKat
- Moto G (2nd Gen) w/KitKat
- Moto X (2nd Gen) w/KitKat
- LG G3 w/KitKat
- Galaxy Note3 w/KitKat

I don't have any KitKat devices and only via the Pre-Launch Reports am I able to "reproduce" this problem.  (Otherwise works as expected on everything I test with.)

Compiled as a Java project.

```
07-11 06:58:18.317: A/libc(10635): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xbdf44066 (code=1), thread 10862 (AsyncTask #3)
07-11 06:58:18.417: I/System(10558): exec(/system/bin/sh -c dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus @ com.google.android.apps.common.walkman.util.DeviceSysCommands.execute:97)
07-11 06:58:18.417: V/HtcNativeCrashUtil(929): Read id1=-1243796867 id2=-217320719, they are start flags. This is HTC header
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): Build fingerprint: 'htc/brightstarus_wwe/htc_m8:4.4.4/KTU84P/389838.5:user/release-keys'
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): Revision: '0'
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): pid: 10635, tid: 10862, name: AsyncTask #3  >>> <com.xyz.myapp> <<<
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): debuggerd: checkTellHTCSettings
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): debuggerd: buildType: user, roAaReport: com, ro.sf: 0
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): debuggerd: rosf: 0
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): debuggerd: [New ROM] isShippingROM: false
07-11 06:58:18.427: I/DEBUG(363): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr bdf44066
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     r0 4205ec68  r1 bdf44052  r2 302d7c76  r3 40427dda
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     r4 00000003  r5 7e59cdd8  r6 81634fd0  r7 4205ec38
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     r8 00000011  r9 4205ec68  sl 00000003  fp 4205ec38
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     ip 00000000  sp 83172c40  lr 00000000  pc 7ba8f978  cpsr a00d0030
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d4  000d006d00700020  d5  003d09000020000a
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d6  0062006d00650076  d7  0031002000720065
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d8  40427dda302d7c76  d9  404272a5bdf44052
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d10 c052fcd07064b945  d11 3fb668e4727848cd
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d12 3f9668e4727848cd  d13 40427572da828f5b
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d14 404272a5bdf44052  d15 4010000000000000
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d16 00000001002b0003  d17 0000000100060101
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d18 6d5e71986d61c900  d19 6d61c9a86d5e71d0
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d20 6d5e72786d5e7240  d21 6d61c7e86d5e72b0
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d22 6d61c8c86d61c820  d23 6d61c9706d61c938
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d24 4024000000000000  d25 4000000000000000
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d26 4000000000000000  d27 547d42aea2879f2e
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d28 4012d97c7f3321d2  d29 bfe3e7b5f9990e90
07-11 06:58:18.557: I/DEBUG(363):     d30 3fd8c36bcf685477  d31 3f811110896efbb2
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):     scr 88000013
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363): backtrace:
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):     #00  pc 00039978  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363): stack:
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c00  4168cc1c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c04  415e8fd8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMalloc(unsigned int, int)+68)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c08  4247b5e0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c0c  415eaaa4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckBefore+552)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c10  41aa5360  [anon:libc_malloc]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c14  416378a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInstanceofNonTrivial+92)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c18  4253e690  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c1c  41b3b890  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c20  6e6df214  /system/framework/core.odex
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c24  78e6e620  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@<com.xyz.myapp>-1.apk@classes.dex
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c28  7e59cdd8  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c2c  81634fd0  [anon:libc_malloc]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c30  00000562  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c34  415dbc40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c38  00000010  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c3c  415e4d60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):     #00  83172c40  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c44  81634fd0  [anon:libc_malloc]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c48  6d5ebf70  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c4c  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c50  83172d78  [stack:10862]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c54  81634fd0  [anon:libc_malloc]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c58  83172c94  [stack:10862]
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c5c  4168cc1c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c60  4247b5e0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c64  415ed868  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+80)
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c68  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c6c  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c70  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c74  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c78  00000000  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):          83172c7c  00000003  
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363): memory near r0:
07-11 06:58:18.567: I/DEBUG(363):     4205ec48 790a7ee6 00004019 41f95b10 00000000  
....
....
07-11 06:58:18.607: I/DEBUG(363): memory map around fault addr bdf44066:
07-11 06:58:18.607: I/DEBUG(363):     8356f000-8376f000 rw- /dev/ashmem/CursorWindow: /data/data/<com.xyz.myapp>/databases/vb_events (deleted)
07-11 06:58:18.607: I/DEBUG(363):     (no map for address)
07-11 06:58:18.607: I/DEBUG(363):     be865000-be886000 rw- [stack]
07-11 06:58:18.607: I/DEBUG(363): --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
....
07-11 06:58:18.957: E/ActivityManager(929): App crashed! Process: <com.xyz.myapp>
07-11 06:58:18.967: W/ActivityManager(929):   Force finishing activity <com.xyz.myapp>/.MainActivity
07-11 06:58:18.987: I/ActivityManager(929): Recipient 10635
```

Based on the SIGSEGV info the reference to my database or the database itself is corrupt?

I also noticed that the HTC One logcat provided a stacktrace of sorts but at that particular location I am simply pulling data out of a cursor provided by the CursorLoader.

```
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): JNI: CheckJNI is off
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): ; workarounds are off
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): ; pins=0
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): ; globals=318
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): DALVIK THREADS:
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635): "main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b4bf30 self=0x41b3a600
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   | sysTid=10635 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074381208
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=145 stm=35 core=0
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at java.lang.String.hashCode(String.java:~924)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:302)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCursor.java:207)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndex(CursorWrapper.java:77)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at <com.xyz.myapp>.sql.AttractionTable.transform(AttractionTable.java:115)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at <com.xyz.myapp>.fragments.MapFragment.transformLocations(MapFragment.java:295)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at <com.xyz.myapp>.fragments.MapFragment.onLoadFinished(MapFragment.java:1168)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at <com.xyz.myapp>.fragments.MapFragment.onLoadFinished(MapFragment.java:81)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:476)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:444)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:105)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:37)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:249)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:77)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:466)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(ModernAsyncTask.java:48)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:483)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
07-11 06:58:18.237: I/dalvikvm(10635):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Nati
ve Method)
```